# SSH ERROR: Unable to write random seed: open("/home/gitlab-runner/.putty/randomseed") returned 'Permission denied'

Tags: ssh, permissions, home, putty

I'm trying to use `plink` to establish a connection to a remote server and remove an entry in SIP user list using the following command:

```
plink root@<ip> -pw pwd serctl ul rm bob
```

which then asks the following:

```
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

No matter what I respond with (`y` or `n`), it replies with:

```
Connection abandoned.
```

I'm kind of stuck and unable to figure out what exactly is the issue and why the below error occurs:

```
ERROR: Unable to write random seed: open("/home/gitlab-runner/.putty/randomseed") returned 'Permission denied'.
```

The issue seems to be with the user profile from where the command is being executed. The user `gitlab-runner` is a user without any password and hence any `sudo` previleges.

Any clues or directions to fix this will be of great help.

**UPDATE:**

It shows the following on `user`:

```
user@PC:~$ namei -l /home/user/.putty/randomseed
f: /home/user/.putty/randomseed
drwxr-xr-x root root    /
drwxr-xr-x root root    home
drwxrwxr-x user group1  user
drwx------ user user    .putty
-rw------- user user    randomseed
```

and the following on the `gitlab-runner`:

```
user@PC:~$ namei -l /home/gitlab-runner/.putty/randomseed
f: /home/gitlab-runner/.putty/randomseed
drwxr-xr-x root          root          /
drwxr-xr-x root          root          home
drwxr-xr-x gitlab-runner gitlab-runner gitlab-runner
drwx------ root          root          .putty
-rw------- root          root          randomseed
```

Clearly the permissions are for `root` for the user `gitlab-runner` here. How can I change that?

Comment: What type or flavor of Unix or Linux are you using? Did you attempt to run the command (or a related putty command) with `sudo` at some point? perhaps the file (or the parent `.putty` directory) has become root-owned

Comment: @steeldriver The command is executed from a user `gitlab-runner` who is not a superuser. So, it does seem like a permission issue. Any clue on how to make this work?

Comment: I'd start by looking at the output of `namei -l /home/user/.putty/randomseed` (or equivalent use of the `ls` command) to make sure that the ownerships/permissions are appropriate all the way down

Comment: I've updated the post with the output of `namei -l`. It looks like `gitlab-runner` doesn't own the directory `.putty`. Is this possible?